# How should a URL be formatted in a Spring WebClient to avoid maximum number of URI tags?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

We are getting a warning in our logs of

```
Reached the maximum number of URI tags for 'http.client.requests'. Are you using 'uriVariables'
```

from `org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.OnlyOnceLoggingDenyMeterFilter` which indicates we are not formatting our URIs as expected.

We were using

```java
    return webClient
        .get()
        .uri(
            builder ->
                builder
                    .path("users/{userId}/summary")
                    .queryParam("timezone", "{timezone}")
                    .build(Map.of("userId", userId, "timezone", timezone)))
```

and that did not work (led to the above warning). That's slightly surprising, since that last argument *is* uriVariables, as the warning recommends using.

We then tried

```java
    String uri = UriComponentsBuilder.fromPath("users/{userId}/summary")
        .queryParam("timezone", "{timezone}")
        .toUriString();
    return webClient
        .get()
        .uri(uri, Map.of("userId", userId, "timezone", timezone)))
    }
```

But that *also* doesn't work, because the brackets around `userId` get encoded, and then userId doesn't get substituted by the uriVariables.

We can fix this by adding a `.build()` ahead of the `.toUriString()` call to turn the builder into `UriComponents` and skip the encoding step, but that's very error-prone (if someone forgets that line). Further, this still feels hacky, because the `.uri(` call then creates a builder another time, and builds again.

How are you supposed to use `uriVariables` in a clean and straightforward way, so that reporting Actuator metrics works well?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this warning and i believe it's because of adding query param `queryParam("timezone", "{timezone}")`. Even though query param is same the url is being created for every request and will be added as `tag` to micrometer metric

The alternative solution we followed is creating complete url with place holders for query param's and path param's since all of them were know at beginning and not dynamically added

```
String url = users/{userId}/summary?timezone={timezone}
```

And then passing the values in `Map`

```
return webClient
    .get()
    .uri(uri, Map.of("userId", userId, "timezone", timezone)))
```

Comment: Thanks; while that would in fact fix it, that's not directly because of passing the `queryParam` to the builder; note that in the original question, I was still able to use `queryParam` passed to a `UriComponentsBuilder`. Rather, building the URL "outside" of the `uri()` call causes the entire string to be considered a tagged metric, which is too many tags.